# Largest value in the functional $\int_0^\infty e^{-rt}( x^2+2x+\dot x^2)dt$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to understand the second order linear differential equation and the answer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7lVu.png) (Finnish) that I have translated below.

**Translation**

> **Problem**
>
> What is the value of $x(t)$ where the functional
>
> $$\int_0^\infty e^{-rt}( x^2+2x+\dot x^2)dt$$
>
> has the largest value when $x(0)=1$?
>
> **Solution**
>
> Problem is autonomous where integrand explicitly depends on time only
>   with respect to the discount factor i.e. $e^{-rt}$. So we need to find
>   a stabilising solution where $\lim_{t_f\rightarrow \infty} x(t_f)=x_s$.
>
> Euler: $1+x+r\dot x -\ddot x=0$
>
> From the initial condition and Euler equation, the solution candidate
>   is
>
> $$x^*=2e^{0.5(r+\sqrt{4+r^2})t}+C_1e^{0.5(r-\sqrt{4+r^2})t}-C_1e^{0.5(r+\sqrt{4+r^2})t}-1$$
>
> Stabilising condition: $\dot x=\ddot x=0$ when
>   $t=t_f\rightarrow\infty$ so according to the Euler the stabilising
>   solution is $x_s=-1$; so integrating constant $C_1$:
>
> $$x^*(t_f)=x_s\Rightarrow
>  C_1=\frac{2e^{0.5(r+\sqrt{4+r^2})t_f}}{-e^{0.5(r-\sqrt{4+r^2})t_f}+e^{0.5(r+\sqrt{4+r^2})t_f}}$$
>
> The limit of the integrating factor $C_1$ when $t_f\rightarrow\infty$
>   is $C_1=2$.

**Cannot understand**

1. where does the Euler equation $1+x+r\dot x -\ddot x=0$ come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\int \mathcal{L}(x,\dot{x},t)dt 
$$
we want to maximize this equation, the Euler-Lagrange equation is of the form
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x} 
$$
where $\mathcal{L} = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left(x^{2} + 2x +\dot{x}^{2}\right)$ 
This results in
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathrm{e}^{-rt}2\dot{x} = -r\mathrm{e}^{-rt}2\dot{x} + 2\ddot{x}\mathrm{e}^{-rt} = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left(2x + 2\right).
$$
Reducing the equation leads to
$$
2\mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left[\ddot{x} - r\dot{x} - x - 1\right] = 0
$$
or we could put it into the form above.

Comment: How did you get this $-r\mathrm{e}^{-rt}2\dot{x} + 2\ddot{x}\mathrm{e}^{-rt} = \mathrm{e}^{-rt}\left(2x + 2\right)$?

Comment: From the Euler Lagrange equation. The left hand side corresponds to the lhs of the E-L equation and similarly for the right hand side ?

Comment: i see that you have accepted the answer on the other question? So is it resolved?

Comment: Yes I finally understood it. Thank you for the attention! It required some patience :)